# Ruby compare 2 arrays of integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say i have 2 arrays with the same length filled with integers

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,3,2,5]
```

And i want to compare these arrays and get an output in new (c) array so it would look like this

```
c = ["+","-","-"," "]
```

An empty space indicates that there is not a current digit in a first array

A - indicates a number match: one of the numbers in the second array is the same as one of the numbers in the first array but in a different position

Currently i have this comparison method and need to improve it

```
a.each_with_index.map {|x, i| b[i] == x ? '+' : '-'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would work: (assuming unique elements)

```
a.zip(b).map do |i, j|
  if i == j
    '+'
  elsif b.include?(i)
    '-'
  else
    ' '
  end
end
#=> ["+", "-", "-", " "]
```

[`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#zip-method) combines the arrays in an element-wise manner and then maps the pairs as follows:

- `'+'` if they are identical
- `'-'` if the element from `a` is included in `b`
- `' '` otherwise

Note that the result still reflects the element order i.e. the position of `'+'` exactly tells you which elements are identical. You might want to sort / shuffle the result.

Comment: quadratic complexity, though

Comment: @SergioTulentsev indeed, but setting up a hash for 4 elements is likely more expensive and I wanted to keep it simple. (assuming the OP is implementing [Mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)))

Comment: Agreed, for inputs this tiny, hashes are likely to be slower.

Answer (score 2):

```rb
appearance = a.each_with_index.to_h
b.map.with_index { |v, i| 
  appearance[v].nil? ? " " : (v == a[i] ? '+' : '-')
}
```

Comment: Works but it is really complicated and hard to read imo

Comment: @Danyil: then use Stefan's answer. It's easier to read, but scales much worse. Might not matter if your arrays don't grow past 4 (which would be the case if you're implementing a certain game)

Comment: optimization idea: you don't need to store positions. `indexes.include?(i)` -> `v == a[i]`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, you're right, `indexes.include?(i)` will be slower if `a`contains many same numbers

Comment: @LamPhan: furthermore, `a.each_with_index.to_h` -> `a.to_set`. You don't need indexes at all. :)